# ( C# / VB FFMPEG Wrapper ) How can I parse progress of conversion video to audio?

Tags: c#, vb.net, ffmpeg, wrapper

I'd try to become specific as much as I can .

I searched a lot to find a good .net wrapper for FFMPEG, the best was [VB FFmpeg Wrapper](http://vbffmpegwrapper.codeplex.com/)

I'm so bad at using VB.net, and the problem was that I want to use this library in a C# project but I couldn't convert the example program I found from VB.net to C# correctly .

So, I've edited my C# application, so it writes input video file path to a temporary .txt file ..  then run the "Converter" ( Which is written in VB ) !

The code of my "Converter" :

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
    Public WithEvents MediaConverter As New FFLib.Encoder

    Private Sub ConOut(ByVal prog As String, ByVal tl As String) Handles MediaConverter.Progress
        OperationPrgrss.Value = prog
        Application.DoEvents()
    End Sub

    Private Sub stat(ByVal status) Handles MediaConverter.Status
        StatusLbl.Text = status
        Application.DoEvents()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Try
            Using PathFinder As New StreamReader("_temp.txt")
                Dim SrcPath As String
                SrcPath = PathFinder.ReadLine()
                PathTxtBox.Text = SrcPath
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("The file couldn't be read : " & Environment.NewLine & ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub


    Private Sub Form1_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Shown
        MediaGenerator.RunWorkerAsync()
    End Sub

    Private Sub MediaGenerator_DoWork(sender As Object, e As ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles MediaGenerator.DoWork
        MediaConverter.OverWrite = False
        MediaConverter.SourceFile = PathTxtBox.Text
        MediaConverter.Format = MediaConverter.Format_MP3
        MediaConverter.AudioCodec = MediaConverter.AudioCodec_mp3
        MediaConverter.Video_Codec = MediaConverter.Vcodec_NONE

        MediaConverter.Threads = 0
        MediaConverter.OverWrite = True

        Dim OutputFldr As String = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "MP3Files\\"
        MediaConverter.OutputPath = OutputFldr
        MediaConverter.AnalyzeFile()

        MediaConverter.Encode()
    End Sub
End Class
```

What I'm trying to do is converting a video file [ sometime it's WEBM, FLV, MP4 or 3GP ],
and the above code does it successfully, but the problem is when using :

```
MediaConverter.Video_Codec = MediaConverter.Vcodec_NONE
```

the progress bar doesn't work, it's value remains 0 !
& When I use any Video codec it works perfectly [ the progress bar ], but the created MP3 file won't work ever with any media player, or in Smartphone & Tv's .. etc ;

...

So, what's the problem ?! and how can I solve it ?
I tried a lot to change some functions in the wrapper library source, but as I mentioned before ... I'm just a newbie @ VB.net :\

Comment: One point.... you do know that could compile the VB.Net wrapper as it's own DLL, then add it as a reference in a C# project so you don't have to write your own code in VB.Net.

Comment: @psubsee2003 ,  Either I'm using C# or VB.net, the same problem exists [ **Why doesn't the progress bar work when choosing to get only audio from a video file ?** ]

And I wish that I know how to convert the above code successfully into C#, it will be awesome so I can integrate it with my program !

but now I'm using the VB.net app as a seperate file next to my C# app ;

Comment: I have not used the library you mentioned before, but I wrote my own wrapper for the FFMPEG CLI previously, and I recall the parsing of the screen output being some very complicated RegEx's due to variations in the screen output.  It is conceivable that the problem could be in the library itself.

Comment: Since you didn't specify, I'm not sure what debugging you have done, but the `Private Sub ConOut` method appears to be reporting the progress.  I'd see what is happening there.  Is this method not getting called or is it getting called but the progress value is 0% (hence your progress bar doesn't update).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to get progress of FFMpeg is parsing its console output.
I've written free and easy-to-use FFMpeg wrapper [Video Converter .NET](http://www.nrecosite.com/video_converter_net.aspx) that has progress event for that:

```
var conv = new NReco.VideoConverter.FFMpegConverter();
conv.ConvertProgress += (o, args) => {
    Console.WriteLine( String.Format("Progress: {0} / {1}\r\n", args.Processed, args.TotalDuration );
};
conv.ConvertMedia(inputFile1, outFile, "flv");
```